# How to display information on a label in second window from the info in the main window

Tags: c#, wpf

HI I'm new to programming. I'm making an app on wpf where i submit some information about an employee such as name dob employee id . there are 4 buttons on the app . save : saves the details, GET brings the details i have put in back  , clear which clears all the info without affecting the classes and show more information, where it shows more info about the employee such as name. etc.

i have got most of this working apart from displaying the label as name in the second window.  the window should only open if the age of the employee is 40 .

```
    private void buttonshow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((int.Parse(textboxmark.Text)) >= 40)
        {

        newWin.ShowDialog();


        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your under the age of 40");
        }

        newWin.label1.Content = employee1.Firstname;
```

is this wrong ?

Comment: If you have not set 'Binding' between window1.TextBox.Text and emplyee1.Firstname your will always be passing empty string to window2.label.Content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the window as new window2 instance as follows and set the employee details through a call to a function that will get a parameter of employee information and then call ShowDialog to show the second window with the employee first name as the label1. function that you need to call before you open the second window, see code below:

```
if ((int.Parse(textboxmark.Text)) >= 40)
{
  Window1 wnd1 = new Window1();
  wnd1.LoadData(employee);
  bool? result = wnd1.ShowDialog();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have not achived the pass mark");
}
```

In the second window you need to create a function to load the data, I named it LoadData as follows:

```
public void LoadData(Employee employee)
{
    label1.Content = employee.FirstName;
}
```

Best regards,

Chen